# using php how can i scrape all fields names and output to a text file?

Tags: php

what i want to try to do is be able to enter say a url onto a variable and once executed the page will scrape all input field names and export it to a text file.

for example.

if i have

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<select name="sex">
<option>...</option>
...
</select>

the output would be

firstname
lastname
sex
```

whats a simple way of doing it?

thanks

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+inurl%3Asarmenhb&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=

Am I reading that right? 68 profiles?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It would let you do something like this:

```
$html = file_get_html($my_address);
foreach($html->find('input, select, textarea') as $input) {
    $names[] = $input->name;
}
file_put_contents('my_output.txt', implode("\n", $names));
```